# Convert a timestamp to date and plot() equivilant in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am having trouble creating a plot and also with converting a timestamp to a date.

The code below pulls data from yahoo finance into a pandas data frame.  The date serves as the index for the dataset in that file and looks like this:

```
2007-05-01 00:00:00
```

Firstly, I would like to convert that index from datetime to date format, but more importantly, I want to figure out out to reproduce the plot obtained from `rels.plot()` in the code below, using matplotlib so that I can add a vertical line on a given date (formatting does not need to be exactly the same.)

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

all_data = {}
for ticker in ['AAPL','MSFT']:
        all_data[ticker] = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '5/1/2007','10/1/2007')

price = pd.DataFrame({tic:data['Adj Close']
                    for tic, data in all_data.iteritems()})

volume = pd.DataFrame({tic:data['Volume']
                    for tic, data in all_data.iteritems()})

returns = price.pct_change()
rels = price/price.ix[0]

rels.plot()

plt.Line2D(rels.index,rels.AAPL)
plt.show()
```

The code above downloads all the data so that you can work with the same data I am using on your machine if need be.  Right now, on my machine in IP[y] notebook, this code runs but the plt.show() does not generate a plot.  The code should generate TWO plots (the first is the reference plot I am trying to re-create with matplotlib.)

Comment: Does anything happen or does it just sit there blank? Also, have you tried anything to resolve it? It works just fine for me.

Comment: It prints out both plots?

Comment: That was it, thanks!  I should have been using plot instead of Line2D.  Do you know how I would go about converting eels.index to a date format rather than date time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Moved from comments to close this:]

Instead of `Line2D`, which simply creates a line object, if you want to actually make a new full plot you want

```
plt.plot(rels.index, rels.AAPL)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strptime and a format to get the date string to insert into the yahoo web.get:

```
 import datetime as dt

 startdate = '5/1/2007'
 enddate = '10/1/2007'

 time_format = "%Y,%m,%d"

 dt_start = dt.datetime.strptime(startdate, time_format)

 dt_end = dt.datetime.strptime(enddate, time_format)

 The rest of the code example****** = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, dt_start,dt_end)
```